Set Clojure CLASSPATH on Windows
I have been struggling to modify my classpath in order to import clojure modules on my Windows machine. I have already updates my environment variable through powershell but I get the same error:
Could not locate menu__init.class, menu.clj or menu.cljc on classpath.
Note:

I have already added (ns db) in db.clj
All my files are in the same directory (app.clj db.clj etc.)
I can not use Leinengen

(ns app
    (:require [clojure.string :as str])
    (:require [db])
    (:require [menu]))

I tried to run: $env:CLASSPATH="." but it did not work. I also tried "." and ".\"
I ran (println (System/getenv "CLASSPATH")) in clj to verify my classpath and it was valid but the code still doesn't run.

How do you run that code?

@EugenePakhomov clj app.clj

Since db seems to work: what is different in menu?

Some vital information is missing here.  If db.clj is beside
app.clj, why does it work?
So ignoring, that db.clj works for some reason, we can assume the
following current situation:
% tree
.
├── app.clj
└── menu.clj

1 directory, 2 files
% clj app.clj 
Syntax error (FileNotFoundException) compiling at (app.clj:1:1).
Could not locate menu__init.class, menu.clj or menu.cljc on classpath.

To see, what paths clj considers (basically) the class-path, you can
run:
% clj -Spath
src:...somejars...

So src is the default, and sticking to the default will spare you
lots of headaches.
Create a src directory in your project and move all your *.clj files
there.  Then run clj src/app.clj (or create a proper -main function
and run it via clj -m app).
-- or --
If you really don't want to have a src directory, then add
a deps.edn file and configure the :paths to include .:
{:paths ["."]}

